# Compared effort when developing Android and iOS app

Tags: iphone, android

Given:

- A desired application called APP wich will present 2 "forms" and will comunicate with a web server to call 3 Web Methods.
- One developer with nearly equivalent expertise on iOS and Android platforms.
- X: required effort to build APP for Android only.
- Y: required effort to build APP for iOS only.
- X = K1 * Y where K1 is a real number.
- Z = K2 * (X + Y) where K2 is a real number and Z is defined as the required effort to build  APP for both Android an iOS.

Please answer:

- What is the approximate value of K1?
- Assuming that the formula for Z is acceptable, what is the approximate value of K2?

Comment: The "forms" would have at most 4 "controls" each and no special UI features would be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends so much on the actual specifications that I think it's impossible to estimate but based on my latest projects that don't have UI customizations I'll make one:

- K1 = 1.4 - I find developing on iOS much faster and easier in this
  case using Interface Builder  and the ASIHTTPRequest library
- K2 = 0.95 - It helps to know the protocol for the web server but in
  this case (3 methods it doesn't matter very much)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The forms would be very simple ones and the services will be WCF ones. Please tell me if I'm wrong with one thing: should I say iOS instead of iPhone?

Comment: doesn't really matter in this case. Since I say Android I prefer iOS to be politically correct :)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO:

K1 = 1.5 Android development is usually slower than iOS and calling web services from Android can be tricky (kSOAP).